# Update one row using sql in jsp

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I am trying to update column "Name" in table "changerequest":

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccb-dbf", "root", "1234");   
String N= name;
String yy="Accepted";
Statement st2= con.createStatement(); 
st2.executeUpdate("UPDATE changerequest SET Status="+yy+"Where Name="+N);
```

What is the syntax error here?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: I guess you need to pass the strings in quotes like this `"UPDATE changerequest SET Status=\""+yy+"\"Where Name=\""+N+"\""`

Comment: Yeah try what I just said.

Comment: Running code like that in a JSP is a **very** bad idea. Create a servlet and use a proper connection pool managed by your servlet container. And you should learn how to use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Variable `yy` and `N` both are String so after concatenation your query

```
UPDATE changerequest SET Status=AcceptedWhere Name=someName
```

No space between `Accepted` and `Where`, Which is not a valid sql query.

Try

```
String query = "UPDATE changerequest SET Status = " + yy + " Where Name = " + N;
Statement st2= con.createStatement();
st2.executeUpdate(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:-

st2.executeUpdate("UPDATE changerequest SET Status="  +yy+ " Where Name="+N);

Note:make a space between set status=? and where clause